# GSAP js function identifier fails when passing string as parameter in another function

Tags: javascript, gsap

I've been working with GSAP tutorial (links below) and wanted to make a function out of this

```
tl.from(img, 1, {y: -20, autoAlpha:0, ease: Bounce.easeOut})
```

so I've created this

```
    // a = selector, b = duration, c = axis, d = offset, e = type of animation, f= easeOut/In

    // Problem occurs when passing c as either 'x'/'y' string

        function test(a,b,c,d,e,f){
    var tl=new TimelineLite;
    var img = $('img');
    var result = tl.from(a, b, c:d, ease:e+'.'+f});
return result;

    }

test('img',2,"y",-370,"Bounce","easeOut");
```

As soon as this runs, it doesn't work and has 0 errors in console as shown here
http://weconnect.ro/stack/

If within the function I modify the `c` identifier to the `y` it runs like magic:
https://weconnect.ro/stack/working.html

I'm fairly new to JS and guess the problem might be that `y` is not really a string (and pretty sure that's not the best method to pass strings from function identifiers).

I'm also clueless on how I would `console.log(this)` as `console.log(test('img',2,"y",-370,"Bounce","easeOut"));` outputs the deconstruction of the TL function which I assume is its objects and that's probably the way to go around constructing it.

Any clarification on the matter would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a complex problem that requires a bit of explanation of some more confusing parts of the JavaScript Language.  I'll try to break this down a bit.

The function `tl.from(img, 1, {y: -20, autoAlpha:0, ease: Bounce.easeOut})` is taking an object (everything inside the `{}`) as the 3rd parameter.  In the format that you have written it, the object is an anonymous object which is created on the fly in the method call.  However, you could *explicitly* create the object, and pass the object as the parameter.

i.e. you could call the function as `tl.from(img, 1, objectWithVariousProperties)`

This leads to the next issue, which is that you are trying to pass a string to your function that represents the name of a particular property.  To be able to access the property in this manner, you would use the JavaScript Object Bracket Notation, rather than Dot Notation.  That looks something like `objectWithVariousProperties[someVariableNamingAProperty]`.

So, putting this together, you would take in your parameters, create an object and prepare it's properties, then pass the object to the function.  Something like the following:

Note I changed the variable names to make the code as clear as possible, and am showing 3 different methods for assigning a value to an Object Property.

```
function test(selector, duration, axis, offset, animation, fadeDirection){

  var tl=new TimelineLite;
  var img = $(selector);

  var propertyObject = {
    autoAlpha: 0   // inline property assignment
  };  
  propertyObject[axis] = offset;  //bracket notation
  propertyObject.ease = animation + '.' + fadeDirection;  //dot notation

  var result = tl.from(img, duration, propertyObject);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the insightful comment, I've thought that in the creation of said object was mandatory, felt that way. I'll re-read once I get home and use the information. It's way clearer now, thank you again!